# Agentive vs Intentional vs Volitional

Tags: terminology, semantics

What are the differences between these three terms?

- Agentivity
- Intentionality
- Volitionality

If they have different definitions, could you provide examples where their values do not match? (For example, a situation where [+agentive] but [-intentional])

Comment: Intentionality and volitionality are the same thing, though different linguists use the term differently, depending on the languages. They both mean that whatever was done by an agent was done on purpose and not by accident. Like the difference between _He poured the water_ and _He spilled the water_; both have an agent, but the action is volitional with _pour_ and non-volitional (or inintentional) with _spill_. In Lushootseed, there is one root meaning either _spill_ or _pour_ with liquid object, but which object pronoun class you use distinguishes them.